# assign a enum variable

Tags: java, enums

i have a problem with my code
i want to assign a simple enum variable and eclipse give me an error "EMPTY cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field"

here is my code
i have a enum class seed like below :

```
public enum Seed {  // to save as "Seed.java"
    EMPTY, CROSS, NOUGHT
}
```

and i have a cell class that inside it i want to use seed class :

```
public class Cell {
    // Package access
    Seed content; // content of this cell (Seed.EMPTY, Seed.CROSS, or Seed.NOUGHT)
    int row, col; // row and column of this cell

    /** Constructor to initialize this cell with the specified row and col */
    public Cell(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        clear(); // clear content
    }

    /** Clear this cell's content to EMPTY */
    public void clear() {
        content = Seed.EMPTY;//**ERROR** EMPTY cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
}
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: The code you've provided compiles fine. Perhaps you've actually got them in different packages, or you've got another `Seed` class somewhere? We can't help you if we can only see working code...

Comment: Make sure to recompile the `Seed` class, you might be running an older version.

Comment: Judging from the error message, the compiler can find the `Seed` class just fine, it just can't find the `EMPTY` field.

Comment: Also check to make sure you're not importing some other Seed class from somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your project and build it and the error will disappear

Comment: i don't know what happened but i close eclipse and run it again and all errors also in other part of my app is gone :) ... thank you all